# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs

Tags: react-native, gradle, sdk

When run the yarn run android suddenly got this error.

BUILD FAILED in 50s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

```
   1.  Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-33.

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
       plugin 7.3.1 is 33.

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
```

==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s

### My build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.5'

    }
}
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()        
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
             force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

Need to build succuss the app.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue, have you by any chance figured out a solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact issue, and found a temporary fix.

In your `android/build.gradle` file, add this line in the ext:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        androidXBrowser = "1.5.0" //<--  add this line here 
    }
}
```

There was a recent update to the dependency `androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01` that has a minimum dependency requirement for Android SDK 34.

In my case, this `androidx:browser` dependency comes from the `react-native-iap` package, which you can view by running `gradlew app:dependencies`.

Source: https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/423